# jquery, sessions & php session_id();

Tags: php, jquery, session, sessionid

I have a session_id which I am using to identify the user in a shopping basket type application.

The session_id is stored in the database as the session id.

When I update the cart, the session_id, product_id and qty are stored in the Basket table.

I am trying to add an item to the Basket, then show the updated basket on the screen without page refresh using jquery.

Do I store the session id in a hidden html field or is there a better way of getting jQuery to know what the session_id is?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so now based on answers and comments below, I don't really want to be using the session id in a hidden field. I certainly don't want to show the session id within the html page.

I may need to backtrack a little...

When ajax is calling my update basket function, I am faced with the following error...

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at ..... /ajaxData.php on line 105
```

The code I am using to start the session is...

```
if (!session_id()){
session_start();
}
```

I don't really understand what this warning means, so this is why I was thinking of sending the session id via the hidden html field.

I guess the solution is to fix what the warning was and try to do things properly...

Any suggestions on my warning message?

Comment: if you would store the session id in a hidden field then you're vulnerably to number of session attacks

Comment: Session id must be invisible

Comment: How is the session ID transmitted so far?

Comment: Point taken. Thank you for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO all session data must be managed in the server, **if you really need it in the front-end** get it asynchronously. For example:

1.- jquery stuff

```
$.get(
        window.location.href,
        {
            get_session_id : 1
        },
    function(data) {
    var session_id = data.session_id
    if ("" == session_id){
            // alert user
            // give a friendly way to proceed without loss user's time
            // return;
    }
    // use session_id
}, "json");
```

**UPDATE**
To avoid `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]...` error put this snippet early as possible in your script. BEFORE any html output.

2.- server stuff

```
// none output before this snippet

if ($_GET['get_session_id'])
{
    // get $session_id
    $output['session_id'] = $session_id ? $session_id : '';
    echo json_encode($output);
    exit;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The reason I propose to you this solution is that I think it is better to get the session ID dynamically when needed, instead of having it stored in a static way, is that this identifier may be modified, deleted, etc., while the user takes his time to fill a form.
Unfortunately this defect is very common and annoying. Submit a form and instead of being processed, we are redirected to a login page, losing all data sent.

Comment: @gravy be sure that all AJAX calls are responded form sever before any output. See my update...

Comment: Why to perform additional ajax request if you can specify the session_id value in place?

Comment: @zerkms what about session expire meanwhile user go for a coffee?

Comment: how is it related? And what would ajax request change? So, session expired after user went for a coffee, so what?

Comment: but it should be `if ( isset($_GET['get_session_id']) ...`

Comment: @zerkms please moderate your tone, is very rude. if you have something to contribute, write it. this solution is one of many but is not wrong in any case. for me I leaving now, have to work...

Comment: @NomikOS: from my point of view it's just wasting HTTP requests. I asked you why it's better - and you took offence instead. Well, ok - you don't have technical explanation for you solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this JavaScript code (combined with PHP):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sessionid = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";
</script>
```

Then use the *sessionid* variable in your jQuery (AJAX?) call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `data-` attribute:

```html
<form id="cart-form" action="" data-sessionid="<?php echo session_id(); ?>">
    <!-- rest of form code -->
</form>
```

Then in your jQuery, just use `$(this).data('sessionid')` to retrieve it:

```
$('#cart-form').submit(function() {
    var session_id = $(this).data('sessionid'); 
    // ... rest of your code here ...
});
```